# Is there any dangers to setuid with root permission on updatedb?

Tags: bash, locate

I'm tempted to use

```
# chmod u+s /usr/bin/updatedb
```

to be able to run it everywhere, anywhere. Is there any reason why I shouldn't ?

I mean, Does it increase insecurity in my system, knowing only root user can use `updatedb`, whereas everyone can use `locate` ?

Comment: Why does anyone *other* than `root` need to run `updatedb`? There is risk with *any* code that runs as `root`, because each such program is a vector for an attack. Programs should run only with the permissions they need, and nothing more.

Comment: because when i create / copy some files to my computer, (git, etc) i have to updatedb to use locate on the new files. I dont use sudo because I dont want my account to have these rights. So when I git clone, I must su - to root, updatedb to log out. thats really shitty

Comment: You can configure `sudo` so that the *only* thing you are allowed to run with `sudo` is `updatedb`.

Comment: Isn't there a way to be able to let updatedb run as a regular user ?

Comment: You can, but then `updatedb` could only index files readable by that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason I can think of is that **`updatedb` isn't already setuid** in any distro I know of, so it might not have been scrutinised to the degree that a normally setuid program would have been. Even `locate` is only **setgid** on Arch Linux:

```
$ stat --format %A $(which locate)
-rwxr-sr-x
```

This means that it's executed with the *group* of the file owner:

```
$ stat --format %G $(which locate)
locate
```

So it's executed as the group "locate", but **as the original user.** This minimises the attack surface to what the "locate" group has access to, which presumably is only the locate database.

setuid and setgid are very rarely things you need to change yourself as a user (I have never needed to in 10+ years of Linux use). Executables from packages are setuid or setgid at install time if they need to be, such as `locate` above or arguably the most famous setuid program, `sudo`:

```
$ stat --format %A $(which sudo)
-rwsr-xr-x
```

`updatedb` is usually run by a cron job. If this is not frequent enough for you you have several alternatives:

- Run `sudo updatedb` (no need for `su`) whenever you want an up-to-date file list.
- Increase the frequency of the cron job. This may be overridden on the next update of the package which installed the cron job in the first place, but on the other hand it might just add another cron job.
- Add another cron job with a higher frequency.
- Run a *service* as root to watch important directories for changes and run `updatedb` when files are added or removed. This might already exist (I dunno), or you can create your own with `inotifywait`. Just make sure of two things:

  1. Don't watch your entire disk for changes, because it will be running `updatedb` constantly.
  2. Don't run one `updatedb` *per file change*, because then you might end up running thousands back to back.

Comment: do you mean that if i install a package (through apt in my case) it will automatically be setuid if configured like so ?

Comment: I like the idea of watching over specific dir to run updatedb. But is there any vulnerabilities to allowing a user to run code as root (like su does, iirc) if this code is always run as root and seem as "innocent" as updatedb ? Lets say someone with bad intentions has access to updatedb. what can he do ?

Comment: That's a very different question, and may be more appropriate for security.SE or unix.SE.